# Rails merge string to existing one when if true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using gem prawn for PDF generation. I want to create table using that gem to do so I'm gonna use `make_cell` from that gem, as follow:

```
  make_cell(
    content: "#{cash_transaction[:transaction_date]}
              \n#{cash_transaction[:creation_date]}
              \n#{cash_transaction[:deletion_date]}"
  )
```

The thing is when `deletion_date(cash_transaction)` is nil it will print we `creation_date` and empty line (which comes from `\n#{cash_transaction[:deletion_date]}`. How to prevent such a situation in more elegant way than below:

```
  if cash_transaction[:deletion_date]
    make_cell(
      content: "#{cash_transaction[:transaction_date]}
                \n#{cash_transaction[:creation_date]}
                \n#{cash_transaction[:deletion_date]}"
    )
  else
    make_cell(
      content: "#{cash_transaction[:transaction_date]}
                \n#{cash_transaction[:creation_date]}"
    )
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you buld the string then pass it to `make_cell`

```
content = "#{cash_transaction[:transaction_date]}
           \n#{cash_transaction[:creation_date]}"

content << "\n#{cash_transaction[:deletion_date]} if cash_transaction[:deletion_date]

make_cell(content: content)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```rb
deletion = cash_transaction[:deletion_date]
deletion = deletion ? "\n#{deletion}" : ''

make_cell(
  content: "#{cash_transaction[:transaction_date]}
            \n#{cash_transaction[:creation_date]}
            #{deletion}"
)
```